# Debug php slim proyect create with composer and skeleton with vscode and xDebug

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code, slim

I'm a newcomer to PHP and I am developing an API with PHP slim.

I'm using Visual Studio Code as IDE and PHP Debug extension.

xDebug is correctly installed in PHP and debug works perfectly a simple code like this when running with XAMPP

```
<?php

$fisrt= 5;

$second= 7;

$result = sum($first, $second);

echo $result;



function sum($a, $b)
{
    $c = $a +$b;
    return $c;
}
```

But I'm stuck with debugging a slim project.
I have created a project with composer:

```
composer create-project slim/slim-skeleton simpleAPI
```

and run it with a simple

```
composer start
> php -S localhost:8080 -t public
[Sun Oct 31 00:01:29 2021] PHP 8.0.11 Development Server (http://localhost:8080) started
```

App works but doesn't stop at breakpoints.

launch.json is auto created whit vscode like this

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
```

vscode: 1.16.2
composer: 2.1.9
php: 8.0.11
slim: 4.7
OS: windows 10

Comment: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings might help. You might  also want to check if the XDEBUG_CONFIG is setup correctly. Also check if there is some option missing. XDEBUG used to be version 2 and there are some breaking changes for  version 3 - make sure to use the recommended settings.

In your index.php file you can call [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to see if the XDEBUG is setup correctly.

I think last time I used it I had to pass something like `?xdebug` to the URL in order to trigger the debugging.

Comment: You have code which you can debug in the webserver, right? Can you debug that code when you run it from the commandline? What are the differences between the webserver and CLI environment? One may be caused by a different user, another may be caused by PHP using different configuration files for different SAPIs. This may have nothing to do with slim and the point of a required [mcve] is to find that out first.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, **the debugger was running** but **nothing stopped at the breakpoint**.

I found something that helped me [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/comments/10bo2o4/visual_studio_code_set_up_debugging_for_slimphp/).

> Solution: fix cwd path; don't use index.php as program

So I pasted this content into my **launch.json** file.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
            "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
            "-S",
            "localhost:8089"
        ],
        "program": "",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/public",
        "port": 9003,
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
            "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
            "action": "openExternally"
        }
    }
]
}
```

I only changed the `localhost:0` to `localhost:8089` where `8089` can be every available port in your system. **With port 0 it didn't work for me.**

**Then I launched the debugger through VS Code and everything worked and now I can debug and set breakpoints!**

Cheers and hope this helps someone!